# Sveltekit: Common +page.server.js file for all routes

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

How can I create a common "+page.server.js" file in SvelteKit that will be read by all pages unless a more specific file exists for a particular page?

Most of my +page.server.js files are the same file since I post the current path to my API. It would be great if I could delete those files and reuse a common one.

Comment: I imagine `+layout` would be the wrong choice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `+layout.server.js` in combination with 'advanced layouts/layout groups' for this. Your file structure would resemble something like this:

```
/src/routes
  /(group-1)
    +layout.server.js
     /route-1
     /route-2
 /route-3
```

in this case only `/route-1` and `/route-2` will have the 'common' code associated with them, while `/route-3` doesn't.

An alternative is to `break out` the layouts with `@`, but personally I find this harder to reason about:

```
/src/routes
  /subroute
    +layout.server.js
    /route-1
      +page.svelte
    /route-2
      +page.svelte
    /route-3
     +page@.svelte
```

This will "reset" the layout for `route-3` back to route.

Both concepts are described in [Advanced Routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get the grouped route to work (conflict with '/'), that's why I solved it with a layout.server.js file. That's working very well, at least for now.